# Add a value into a textbox from a combobox with if

Tags: c#

Simple case, comboBox1 displays a list of items, when the user clicks on any item I want the price of that item placed into a textbox

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "LED")
    {
        textBox1.Text = "20";
    }
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Ahorradores")
    {
        textBox1.Text = "50";
    }
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Incandecentes")
    {
        textBox1.Text = "100";
    }
}
```

I can't make it work, also if anyone knows how to do this as well in excel would be great, I have searched a lot and didn't find answers

Comment: I have tried SelectedValue and SelectedText too and didn't work

Comment: Can  you show how you're populating the comboBox?

Comment: These don't look like nested ifs to me...the whitespace is misleading.

Comment: can u try `comboBox1.Text` instead.

Comment: I fill the comboBox via properties -> Items collection

Comment: Show some code so someone can help you.  Create a minimal, working example : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show exactly how you're adding those items.

Comment: is Items List<Object> or List<String> ???

Answer (score 1):

You should probably go for a better option than hardcoding your values in the combo's event. For example, you can create a class for the elements:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

When populating the combobox, do that by using this class and setting its values from the database or whatever your data source is. Hardcoded example:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(new Element() { Name = "LED", Price = 20 });
comboBox1.Items.Add(new Element() { Name = "Ahorradores", Price = 50 });
comboBox1.Items.Add(new Element() { Name = "Incandescentes", Price = 100 });
```

And then, put this in the event:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Element element = comboBox1.SelectedItem as Element;
    textBox1.Text = element.Price.ToString();
}
```

Note that I fixed your typo in "incandescentes".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, filling the comboBox works this way but when clicking nothing happens, I added the class as a new class to the project am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, if it's not working yes, you are doing something wrong. But I'm not a wizard so I don't know what you actually did. :P Place a breakpoint in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` to debug it!

Comment: @RobertoMisc, any update?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Text Property here. Like this

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (comboBox1.Text)
    {
        case "LED":
            textBox1.Text = "20";
            break;
        case "Ahorradores":
            textBox1.Text = "50";
            break;
        case "Incandecentes":
            textBox1.Text = "100";
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little hack that I like to use when I am feeling lazy. Any text after `\0` is not displayed.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = "LED\020 Ahorradores\050 Incandecentes\0100".Split();
```

then to get the part after `\0`

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Split('\0')[1];
    textBox1.Text = (comboBox1.SelectedItem as string ?? "").Split('\0').LastOrDefault();
}
```